# Render simple JSON array with RABL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I've been trying to figure out how to make RABL render a very simple JSON array of string, such as: `["my,"array","of","strings"]`

The controller would be

```
class StringsController < ApplicationController
    responds_to :json

    def index
        @string = ['my','array','of','strings']
        respond_with @strings
    end

end
```

And the RABL view must surely start with:

```
collection @strings, root_object: false
```

but I cannot figure out how to just output the strings without a node name or within an object...

There is obviously a much more straightforward solution to actually serving up the JSON array, much like what I've put below, but I'm specifically interested in why this seems so complicated in RABL!

```
class StringsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        render json: ['my','array','of','strings']
    end

end
```

Comment: In rabl the collection will take json object not array.

Answer (score 1):

Neill,

This should work for any arrays, but for your particular array the exact answer is...

In the index.json.rabl use the below code

```
collection @string, object_root: false

node do |s|
  s 
en
```

In your controller use...

```
def index 
    @string = ["my","array","of","strings"]
end
```

Comment: Afraid that this doesn't work for me.  The RABL template that you have given produces the JSON `[{},{},{}]`, not `['my','array','of','strings']`
(I'm using RABL version 0.9.3, if that makes any difference)

Comment: I see that your array was in @string, try that now, but don't respond_with, just use render and use my response in index.json.rabl

Comment: I've tried setting this up as a view spec on the RABL template, so it is detached from the controller and it still just renders the empty objects instead of the strings.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that your array is called [at]string and the collection is [at]strings. Try changing the collection name to match the variable you are using. You shouldn't need respond_with just a render call.

Comment: Woops..!  Unfortunately, that's just a typo in what I've put in opening post :)  Still no luck with this, it doesn't matter whether I use `#respond_to` or not,. I get the empty object array.  I've decided to look at jbuilder instead, which allows me to do this easily.  It seems like giving up, but I've spent a lot of time trying to find out how to get this simple representation to work....

Comment: Its weird because the code I have given you is exactly what I use. Good luck with jbuilder, I have never used it. 
Can you post the rabl template you are using?

Answer (score 1):

To build on top of Mark's answer, I think it works with this:

```
collection @string, object_root: false

node :value do |s|
  s 
end
```

Note I added `:value` which is the label of the JSON record.

Comment: is there any way to have dynamic key rather than having a static key as value??

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like that and that need not the rabl view for showing response.

```
def index
    @string = ['my','array','of','strings']
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json  { render :json => {:message => "Success", :my_string => @string } }
      format.xml
    end
  end
```

Comment: That solution will not render a simple array of strings, and is also not answering my question about rendering the array with RABL.  I want the JSON output to simply be `["my,"array","of","strings"]` and, although there are other approaches, I would like to know specifically how to achieve this in RABL.